# Is logging to a message queue a good idea?

Tags: logging, messaging

Currently I'm facing the problem to aggregate several log files from a distributed system.

But since most of the applications are Java applications which use both log4j and all of them use JMS I thought about logging directly into a message queue instead of copying the individual log files.

Is this a good idea or can this backfire somehow?

Comment: Depends on log file quantities, size and frequency. i.e: If you are sure logs will not kill your server, then go for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of loose ideas:

- performance was already mentioned — turning on detailed debug information may prove impossible in production environment (if it turns out you need to trace for a deeply hidden error),
- you lose log4j's roll-over behaviour, you have to implement it yourself at the point where you collect log statements,
- add process/machine specific info to log lines (unless it's obvious otherwise which application issued which log line),
- consider adding an incrementing counter of log lines in every application if you absolutely need to know the order in which log statements were issued — message delivery order is not guaranteed and time stamp in log4j is only at millisecond increments,
- efficient analysis of such bulky file may require good (and paid, or even custom-written) log viewers.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to do that, I would log to both. That way if you have to troubleshoot your JMS logging you have a log4j log. Just configure the log4j appender to keep the log files small since you will mostly use the JMS log.

Answer (score 0):

- Log4j (in your case) or preferrably NXLog (http://nxlog-ce.sourceforge.net/)
- Some log shipping agent (nxlog.exe) shipping the log files into
- The ELK stack (Elasticsearch, Logstash and Kibana) which you run as docker containers

https://www.elastic.co/webinars/introduction-elk-stack.